# How can I spread out my select element to div element?

Tags: html, css, html-select

Please check my design before reading the question:
[My Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxK5X.png)

I want spread out "select-option" element to div element.
Like these:
[First Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMIhs.png),
[Second Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmoZb.png)

But I can't spread out. How can I spread out combobox to div element?
I also tried to delete *input-field.month*'s padding and add padding to select element. It worked, but it is not seems like my numeric input element.

```css
.input-field {
background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, #ffffffaa 0%, #ffffffee 50%, #ffffffaa 100% );
background-size: 200%;
font-size: 0.8rem;
font-weight: 700;
letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
color: #000000bb;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-radius: 0.5rem;
box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 10px -3px #00000025;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.input-field.money {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.25rem;
}
.input-field.month {
  padding: 0.25rem 2rem;
}
.input-field:hover {
  background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field month">
  <div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control form-select bg-transparent border-0" id="aySayisi">
      <option class="bg-transparent border-0" *ngFor="let kredivadesi of krediVadeleri" value="{{kredivadesi.aySayisi}}">{{kredivadesi.aySayisi}} Ay</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its  unclear what you are trying to achieve. you want padding where ? in the select ?

Comment: @dippas yes. It should look like this: option arrow should in right. option's box and div's box should be the same.

Comment: so as you said, just remove `padding` from `month` and add to `select`

Comment: have a look at css grid